# Loader icon Constantly Displaying In my App.JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loader

I am trying to add a loader icon to my site but it is constantly showing should i put it in a component and import it? The state is set to true as the page is loading when it refreshes maybe its something with this.

This is my app.js file

```
import React from "react";

import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";
import { Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

import "assets/scss/material-kit-react.scss?v=1.4.0";

// pages for this product
import LandingPage from "views/LandingPage/LandingPage.jsx";
import ProfilePage from "views/ProfilePage/ProfilePage.jsx";
import { css } from "@emotion/core";
// First way to import
import { ClipLoader } from "react-spinners";

const override = css`
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-color: red;
`;
var hist = createBrowserHistory();

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      loading: true
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <ClipLoader
          css={override}
          sizeUnit={"px"}
          size={150}
          color={"#123abc"}
          loading={this.state.loading}
        />
        <Router history={hist}>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/profile-page" component={ProfilePage} />
            <Route path="/" component={LandingPage} />
          </Switch>
        </Router>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: The default value of `loading` is `true`. So, isn't it normal to see the loader constantly? It should be `false` at the first render. When you do something and want to display the loader you should set the state to `true` and when the job is done you should revert it again to `false`.

Comment: I don't think you need a loader here.  Use it when you make network requests. like here https://stackblitz.com/edit/movie-api?file=index.js or here https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-qwj7xv

Answer (score 1):

your default state is set to true. so it will show the loading once the component renders

```
   this.state = {
      loading: false
    };
```

You can change your Loader to a HOC

```
import React from 'react';
import { ClipLoader } from "react-spinners";

function Loading(Component) {
  return function WihLoadingComponent({ isLoading, ...props }) {
    if (!isLoading) return (<Component {...props} />);
    return (<ClipLoader
          css={override}
          sizeUnit={"px"}
          size={150}
          color={"#123abc"}
          loading={isLoading}
        />);
  }
}
export default Loading;
```

Then you can use you global context or redux store to update the state of `isLoading`

```
render() {
    return (
      <Loading isLoading={this.props.isLoading} data={data} />
    )
  }
```

Comment: so my loader is rendering on false why cant i see it??

Comment: @TheGreenLightbulb im not quite getting what you are tying to say. but its because its being controlled through the `loading` prop. thats why you cant see it